# Как поступать при необходимости выполнять большое количество сложных однотипных SQL запросов

Tags: sql, алгоритм

Давайте пофантазируем:

У нас есть некая гипотетическая БД, из которой периодически необходимо получать данные по, скажем, пользователям.

Выборку пользователей необходимо осуществлять некоторому набору фильтров, в общем - скукота.

Добавим набор параметров для каждого пользователя, извлекать которые будет сколько-то трудозатратно, например, будем к каждому пользователю пристегивать информацию о том, сколько уникальных посещений сайта другими пользователями было зафиксировано с момента последнего посещения текущим пользователем. Или еще что-то в этом роде, т.е. информацию, требующую осуществления дополнительных телодвижений и JOIN'ов.

Примем за истину то, что у нас есть некоторое количество мест в проекте, в которых возникает необходимость получить из БД информацию о пользователях, при этом в каждом месте мы имеем разные(сильно пересекающиеся) комбинации необходимых возвращаемых полей.

Как поступать в подобной ситуации? Я вижу следующие подходы:

1. *Писать один запрос, который будет заправшивать всю информацию, и использовать его всегда*. Не самым умный подход, он скушает большое количество ресурсов даже в случае когда можно обойтись малой кровью. Возможно подход жизнеспособен при глубоком кэшировании результатов
2. *Писать по запросу под каждую конкретную задачу*. Наиболее производительно, но код начинает изобиловать почти одинаковыми методами с аналогичными названиями, и сильно пухнет. Возможно подход жизнеспособен при стабильно малом количестве вариантов необходимых комбинаций возвращаемых полей.
3. *Автоматически генерировать запрос неким методом, прямо передавая в этот метод список полей, которые необходимо получить в ответ*. Получаем максисально производительные запросы под полный спектр вариаций возвращзаемых полей, однако можем получить (и, вероятно, получим) слабодиагностируемый здоровенный, сложный метод, трогать который, после написания, строго не рекоммендуется.
4. *Создать набор методов с простейшими запросами и жонглировать ими в основном используемом ЯП* (в сабже - php). Т.е. сначала выбрали всех пользователей по фильтрам, потом пристегнули каждому необходимые данные... попахивает неприлично большим количеством запросов и смертью производительности при больших количествах строк. Так же будут проблемы в случаях если фильтры по которым осуществляется выборка относятся к дополнительным возвращаемым полям

В общем хочется увидеть ваше мнение на вопрос. Возможно упоминание каких-то подводных камней, которых я не увидел.

**UPD:**
Особо интересны мысли по поводу варианта динамической генерации запроса. Возможно существуют какие-то материалы, в которых данный вопрос освещался? ТС всегда относился крайне негативно к автоматической генерации любого исполняемого кода (как SQL так и JS), но в контексте такой подход выглядит вполне приличным если сделать все аккуратно. Вы как считаете?

Comment: - Ответ, на мой взгляд - очень простой. Нужно написать самый очевидный код, который только возможен и, только лишь в том случае, если его производительность **не будет вас устраивать,** то проводить оптимизацию.

- Тем более, если вы напишете тесты на этот тривиальный метод, то они останутся актуальными и для (потенциально) соптимизированной версии.

Comment: мне кажется у вас какая-то лажа с субд или имплементация логики приложения что приводит к дополнительной нагрузке субд. в принцыпе некоторые данные которые редко меняются можно дублировать в разных таблицах, это позволит уменьшить количество join's

Comment: @Павел Вершинин вы пишите, что структура базы плохо продумана, если приходится часто использовать join'ы.Либо вы имеете в виду совсем другое, либо имеете слабое представление о проектировании баз. Вы сами можете нагуглить по словам "тормозят join'ы" кучу запросов, которые столь же показательны как и неправильны. На хэшкоде бывают и вопросы и ответы далекие от понимания что такое оптимальные запросы.Это нисколько не является показателем чего-либо. В каждом отдельном случае необходимо проводить исследования.В вашем примере вы эти исследования очевидно не проводили. Вывод неверный в общем случае

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Моё мнение следующее. Выбор одного из перечисленных вариантов - это как раз одно из тех решений, для принятия которых разработчик и нужен в проекте. Его отчасти для того и привлекают к решению задачи, чтобы он, зная конкретные особенности проекта, мог с учётом своего опыта выбрать наилучший вариант.

Answer (score 3):

1) Если вам часто приходится писать запросы с JOIN, значит у вас плохо продумана архитектура БД. Возможно имеет смысл дополнить какие-то таблицы новыми полями, БД конечно весить будет поболее, из-за дублирующихся данных, но это не столь страшно.

2) Если извлекаемые данные не слишком часто меняются, правильно будет их [кешировать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108274/). Тогда п.1 уже не столь актуален

3) Если данные меняются слишком часто и п.2 не подходит, при этом делается огромное кол-во однотипных запросов к БД (В рамках одной сессии) поэтому п.1 уже не очень выручает. Спасти ситуацию могут [статические переменные](http://php.su/learnphp/vars/?statvars) Например:

```
/**
* Некая функция для получения данных из БД
* @static array $result Статическая переменная, для хранения результата
* @param array $params Параметры запроса
*/
function get_data($params = array())
{
     static $result = array(); 
     $key = serialize($params); // Уникальный ключ, собранный из параметров запроса
     if(isset($result[$key])
     {
          return $result[$key]; // Если ключ имеется возвращаем данные
     }
     ...
     /// Тут делаем запрос к БД и сохраняем результат в $result[$key]
     ...
     return $result[$key]; //Возвращаем результат
}
```

Таким образом вы избавитесь от однотипных запросов, при этом всегда будете получать самые "свежие" данные из БД. Однако у этого варианта есть недостаток, [жрет собака оперативку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141093/))))

Дисклеймер. Это не истина в последней инстанции, а лишь моё личное мнение)))

Comment: @Павел Вершинин п.1 означает, что база нормализована?

Comment: Первый пункт - бред. То, что mysql, например, тормозит на джойнах это проблема mysql'я а не архитектуры бд. Запросы без  джойнов - это вариант dBASE, когда в память берутся все таблицы. И джойны, если и нужны, делаются в памяти. Ни о каких нормальных формах при этом речи естественно не идет.  
Не совсем понятно, чем кардинально отличается 2 и 3 пункт?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov 
Первый пункт совсем таки не бред, убедился на своем опыте. Когда-то, я написал и поддерживал, довольно нагруженный скрипт AutoSEO http://forum.searchengines.ru/showthread.php?t=596514 в общих чертах эта система принимает запросы от десятков а порой и сотен подключенных к ней сайтов, с ней я на собственном опыте убедился насколько тормозят JOIN-ы. Всего один запрос с двумя соединениями тормозил систему, а у некоторых клиентов даже ложил сервер. После того как я разделил этот запрос на три простых все тормоза исчезли.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov 
Второй вариант, делает "долгий" кеш который доступен всем процессам достаточно длительное время. Если данные часто меняются он непригоден. Третий вариант, кеширует данные в рамках одного процесса, его и кешом то, в полном смысле, называть неправильно. Он прекрасно спасает когда одни и те-же данные в процессе загрузки странички надо получать мноооого раз и при этом эти самые данные постоянно меняются, ну что-то типа примера из вопроса ТС.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, если отбросить вопрос нормализации, то это никак не бред, join'ы нереально тормозят независимо от качества их реализации, вообще, если вы планируете написать расширяемый проект и у вас в архитектуре намечается много join'ов, то стоит задуматься от использовании нереляционного хранилища данных.

Лучше всего понять всю печальность происходящего поможет гугление на тему того, как вобще хранятся данный в SQL БД и как именно работают join'ы.

Собственно настоятельно рекомендую ознакомится

Comment: @Павел Вершинин ваш пример некорректен, мы не видим структуру, не видим запросы, которые "ложат сервер". То, что кто-то может написать неоптимальный запрос, который будет класть не только mysql, но и оракл, не вызывает сомнения, но говорить, что "лучше у меня будет одна таблица только бы написанный мной запрос не тормозил" как минимум нелогично.

Comment: @AlexWindHope "реальные тормоза" лежат в плоскости оптимизации запросов, а не в плоскости "ща мы все зафигачим в одну таблицу и все будет летать". Если база работает только на insert и select одних и тех же наборов данных и пофигу на размер, 3НФ не нужна "конечно". Это путь мертвого dbf. В вебе все считают время отклика и запросы больше секунды - повод хвататься за голову.  
ЗЫ Про noSQL речи нет, другие задачи, другие проблемы.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я, как-бы, вообще не об этом, я вам о Фоме, вы мне о Ереме

Comment: Пункт первый вне контекста - действительно бред. Что касаемо идеи избыточность данных в обмен на производительность - тут есть здравое зерно и OLAP тому пример

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я как бы о первом пункте ответа. Вы мне про нереальные тормоза без привязки к какой-либо структуре БД и цифрам (нереальные тормоза - это ~секунды или ~минуты?). Этими вопросами занимаются DBA. Когда есть нормальная структура БД, есть нормальный запрос и он тормозит, с ситуацией разбираются специально обученные люди, анализируют таблицы, индексы и т.д.  
Утверждение о том, что join'ы зло, принятый как аксиома, неверно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Разве я или кто-то утверждал что JOIN-ы зло? Помоему нет. Я лишь написал, что частое использование JOIN-ов не самое лучшее решение. И если от JOIN-а в запросе можно легко отказаться то так и надо делать.

По поводу моего примера, какие цифры вам нужны? Это реальный опыт из моей практики трехлетней давности, ни кода, ни запросов у меня сейчас уже не осталось, ну не могу же я хранить все что понаписал за свою жизнь :)

А если вам нужны цифры, погуглите, я бы даже сказал поХАБРите там куча статей с тестами и цифрами :)

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос в том для чего вы хотите использовать БД. Если как абстрактное хранилище, то, на мой взгляд, Вам надо определить объектную модель данных, исходя из ваших предпочтений по удобству, а внутрях тюнить как хочется. И, уйти от SQL в прикладном коде совсем. Если же использовать БД по полной, то писать код так чтобы не мешать БД выполнять свою работу по оптимизации и т.д. Причём второй способ никоем образом не исключает первый. Разделение прикладной части и системной помогает разделить задачи по оптимизации и передачи их специализирующихся на этом людям.

Answer (score 1):

1. На это даны нам хранимые процедуры? Напишите хранимую процедуру которая выполняет такие частые запросы
2. На многих языках высокого уровня есть понятие [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), смысл состоит в том, чтобы хранить прекомпилированный запрос, в котором меняются только параметры. Выигрыш достигается за счет экономии времени на компиляцию запроса SQL сервером. Не знаю как там насчет PHP, но в C#/Java - это все реализовано как говорится на "высшем уровне".

**Update**

Да, вижу что PHP поддерживает Prepared Statement, типа:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду подробнее просвещаться в эту сторону.

Однако поможет ли это в освещенном случае - когда в различных запросах нам нужно использовать разные JOIN'ы в различном количестве (иногда вообще можно без них обойтись).

У запросов аналогична бОльшая часть, однако различия все-же весьма и весьма существенны.

Comment: ясно осознавая тот факт, что под тэгом sql подавляющая часть аудитории подразумевает MySQL, все таки укажу следующую возможость для MS SQL - хинт RECOMPILE

Answer (score 1):

Oracle, в частности, хранит результаты идентичных запросов. Не близких по значению, конечно, но всё равно. По большей части это дело СУБД и Администратора БД, кешировать или нет.